# what is the difference between two Eigenvalue[...] outputs

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Can someone explain the difference between two types of `Eigenvalue[...]` operations:

```
type 1:  a + 0 i (MMA returns a complex eigenvalue but the imaginary part is multiplied by 0, which in effect means an insignificant imaginary part?)

Type 2: a  (MMA returns a real-valued eigenvalue)
```

What is the difference between the two types of outputs? How should be interpreted?

**EDIT**

Here is the matrix that generates the complex eigenvalues:

```
{{1.16477, 0.356828, 0.0714408, 0.0476947, 0.0453199, 0.0300033, 0.0209801, 0.0127449, 0.086416, 0.00929001, 0.00956968, 0.0154812, 0.00731831, 0.0210249, 0.0219437}, {0.120069, 1.204, 0.041706, 0.109533, 0.132376, 0.0647538, 0.0274431, 0.0253398, 0.15743, 0.0179913, 0.0175686, 0.0268473, 0.0134596, 0.0398652, 0.0455229}, {0.00658812, 0.00971866, 1.42106, 0.0298236, 0.0100892, 0.0184267, 0.0127866, 0.00865431, 0.00779337, 0.00374859, 0.00422125, 0.00910543, 0.00299431, 0.0139231, 0.0185264}, {0.127827, 0.177148, 0.242241, 1.63018, 0.280833, 0.563288, 0.112815, 0.19545, 0.112243, 0.0625146, 0.0820313, 
0.0820096, 0.0392132, 0.221223, 0.129502}, {0.0485159, 0.0918359, 0.101534, 0.177235, 1.73542, 0.0891488, 0.0614551, 0.065333, 
0.0674608, 0.0386922, 0.0547707, 0.0561997, 0.0386834, 0.0822336, 0.0851243}, {0.0103604, 0.016981, 0.0157314, 0.0238212, 0.0612969, 
1.15536, 0.0194269, 0.019397, 0.0157551, 0.0144135, 0.0307544, 0.0277547, 0.00994415, 0.0152484, 0.0183958}, {0.0967337, 0.173557, 
0.212141, 0.166091, 0.12537, 0.130403, 1.05936, 0.088435, 0.0916659, 0.0279539, 0.028663, 0.037726, 0.0171214, 0.0972102, 
0.0595427}, {0.0486714, 0.0996562, 0.109242, 0.129804, 0.102714, 0.103125, 0.0991559, 1.2266, 0.0555611, 0.039711, 0.0390155, 0.0415404, 0.019529, 0.0476566, 0.0530335}, {0.0128437, 0.0234157,  0.0286443, 0.0368054, 0.0472341, 0.0347211, 0.0397455, 0.0403333, 1.07898, 0.0633738, 0.0377117, 0.0396082, 0.0183556, 0.042109, 0.0513172}, {0.0178072, 0.0244885, 0.0290222, 0.0379916, 0.0528874, 0.0365446, 0.0311718, 0.0334347, 0.0223253, 1.20594, 0.0355465, 0.0211309, 0.00865396, 0.0202845, 0.0265796}, {0.0344373, 0.067, 0.0803042, 0.0992088, 0.126276, 0.115809, 0.141134, 0.0865641, 0.0968464, 0.104234, 1.08747, 0.0698113, 0.0370082, 0.0705821, 0.109838}, {0.0139976, 0.0176454, 0.00926675, 0.014673, 0.0172447, 0.0116089, 0.0118301, 0.0116727, 0.0301583, 0.0120813, 0.0415707, 1.10983, 0.034964, 0.0370641, 0.0530764}, {0.00852312, 0.0224126, 0.0250497, 0.0335736, 0.0426726, 0.0260864, 0.0280763, 0.0303417, 0.025725, 0.0573826, 0.0241575, 0.0670001, 1.09338, 0.0401698, 0.0491595}, {0.0099866, 0.0167077, 0.0129667, 0.0248066, 0.0339806, 0.0208063, 0.0228903, 0.0295363, 0.0176227, 0.0448973, 0.0154321, 0.0166424, 0.00584395, 1.05841, 0.0497809}, {0.00592217, 0.0106941, 0.0111646, 0.0152356, 0.0172162, 0.0120184, 0.0121028, 0.0118887, 0.0210621, 0.0162441, 0.0138071, 0.0164373, 0.00925642, 0.0229111,  1.11133}}
```

Comment: Please show us your actual code. Are you using exact `0` or approximate `0.`?

Comment: I gave the full matrix that generates the complex eigenvalues. Please take a loot at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *Mathematica* 12.1.0.0. If `a` is your matrix,

```
Eigenvalues[a]
```

yields complex eigenvalues, some with approximately zero imaginary parts like `2.19393 + 0. I`, and some with nonzero imaginary parts. Your matrix uses machine numbers. *Mathematica* does not track precision for these, so it cannot distinguish between a complex number with approximately zero imaginary part and a real number.

Using controlled precision,

```
Eigenvalues[SetPrecision[a, 20]]
```

yields real numbers for the real eigenvalues and complex numbers for the complex ones.

Converting each of your approximate numbers to a nearby rational number, we can obtain an exact solution for those exact numbers:

```
Eigenvalues[Rationalize[a, 0]]
```

The result is an expression containing large `Root` objects. These are exact: if their imaginary parts are 0, they are real, and if not they are complex. Their numerical values closely match those from the other two methods.

I don't understand your assertion about `a+0 I`. Since `0 I` is zero, that expression represents a matrix identical to `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand  that `0 I` must be zero, but if it is zero, why on earth MMA gives me `0 I` instead of just giving the real value. This was my confusion. As you noted, my ignorance was about the machine number versus real numbers.

Comment: @TugrulTemel It doesn't give you `0 I`. It gives you `0. I`. The first is **exactly** zero, while the second is **approximately** zero, so perhaps not truly zero.

Comment: That is right. Does this mean that the second  output `0. I` actually has an imaginary part? If so, how can MMA approximate an imaginary number?

Comment: @TugrulTemel Compare `FullForm[0. I]` with `FullForm[0 I]` to see how *Mathematica* encodes the two cases.